# Debian - Can't execute a bash script at a certain time

Tags: bash, debian

So, I'm trying to run a bash script at a certain time, and I set up a simple test to create a folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /root/test/testcreate
```

Then, I executed it with this job in `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/test/downloadtest4.sh
```

However, when I set the first two asterisks to a specified numbers, then it won't execute. My thoughts are that I am somehow inputting the time wrong.

I execute `date` and it shows up with something like

```
Wed Aug  6 14:30:05 EDT 2014
```

At which point I change my job in `crontab -e` to:

```
32 14 * * * /bin/bash /root/test/downloadtest4.sh
```

And then I wait a couple minutes for it to execute, but nothing happens.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked whether cron uses a different time zone?

Comment: `* * * * *  date > /tmp/date.txt`

Comment: @that other guy How do I do that? If I do it using @Cyrus way, then the date.txt file returns `Wed Aug  6 15:06:01 EDT 2014`. It's the same as when I execute `date`

Comment: Are there any hints: `grep cron /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: This is all I have @Cyrus. Nothing looks useful. `Aug  6 15:42:17 rosaserver crontab[2329]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Aug  6 15:42:51 rosaserver crontab[2329]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Aug  6 15:42:51 rosaserver crontab[2329]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Aug  6 15:43:01 rosaserver /usr/sbin/cron[480]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Aug  6 15:43:40 rosaserver crontab[2338]: (root) LIST (root)`

Comment: @Cyrus I figured it out. Apparently, cron is using a time that is 6 hours ahead of me. I tried changing the `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime` but neither of those made a difference.

Comment: My Debian /etc/crontab has a user field and the comment 
`# These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.`
eg.
`25 3 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`
but this might just be because I'm using a laptop and anacron.

Answer (score 1):

The cron daemon runs with a defined timezone.  That timezone is defined when the daemon starts.

In Debian's `/etc/init.d/cron` you can see the lines:

```
if [ -z "$TZ" -a -e /etc/timezone ]; then
    TZ=`cat /etc/timezone`
fi
```

So, cron's timezone is the one specified in file `/etc/timezone`.  After changing that file, you will have to restart the cron daemon:

```
invoke-rc.d cron restart
```